# Allow 2 duplicate ip addresses maximum php csv

Tags: php, csv, ip

I have an issue with a processing script.  I would like to allow 2 duplicate ip addresses maximum in a csv file, to prevent some spamming and to take into consideration that the user could make a mistake in form fill.  I cant seem to reference the $ip variable correctly in the script, or there might be something I am missing altogether.  Here is the code snippet thus far:

```
<?php
#VARIABLE DECLARATIONS (filename and post vars) GO HERE
$counter = 0;
if (file_exists($filename)) 
{
    $file = fopen($filename, "a");
    while($data = fgetcsv($filename)){
       if(isset($data[$ip])){
           $counter++;
           continue;
           if((isset($data[$ip])){
               $counter++;
               if($counter == 2){
                   echo "";
                }
           }
        }
     }
     ##file write goes here
}

?>
```

Any help on this would be appreciated,

Jim

Comment: When your script starts working, does it have the empty csv file, or it already has some data? Do you write the csv file reading from an array or after reading from the same csv file (i.e. your script effectively removes extra IPs from the csv file)?

Comment: Nothing after `continue` will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The .csv file already has the data in the file with headings, and the .csv file is written to after reading from the same .csv file.

Comment: When you say 2 duplicates, do you mean that two different addresses can each appear multiple times, or one address can have a single duplicate? Could you show a sample of the CSV, and show what you want to allow and disallow?

Comment: Here is an example of the csv file, the ip address can appear twice in the file maximum:    Mr,Test,davis,07972889989,01159174767,92.27.21.171
Mr,bob,jones,07998998008,01159174767,92.27.21.171
#these two records would be fine (with the matching ip's) but;
Mrs,Tina,jonson,07975666777,01798998998,92.27.21.171
#the record (Tina) above should not be included as there is now more than 2 duplicates in the .csv file

Answer (score 0):

You will have to read all the elements in an array first and only after you have the number of occurrences of each IP address ready, should go ahead with writing the file (a separate file may be?).

You can first prepare an array with IP indexes and all the rows corresponding to an IP as value attributes to that key. 
This could be done -

```
$csvArray = str_getcsv(file_get_contents('myCSVFile.csv'));

foreach($csvArray as $eachRow)
{
     //prepare IP indexed array with every detail row as an attribute of the corresponding IP key.
     $properlyFormattedArray[$eachRow[5]][] = $eachRow;
}
```

You get an array like this -

```
Array(['92.27.21.171'] => 
         [0] => Array("Mr","Test","davis","07972889989","01159174767","92.27.21.171"),
         [1] => Array("Mr","bob","jones","07998998008","01159174767","92.27.21.171"),


      ...
      ['92.27.21.172'] => ...

)
```

Once you have this array, just loop over it, and write only at max 2 rows for every IP.

```
foreach($properlyFormattedArray as $ip => $details)
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach($details as $eachDetail)
    {
       if($count<2)
       {
            //write $eachDetail into file
            $count++;
       }
    }

}
```

But, in this case, the order of data (compared with your input file) will be changed, and the duplicates will be written in consecutive rows in the csv file (not sure if you would be okay with it).

Comment: Thank you for the insight and assistance, I will post back when I have solved the issue

Comment: Thanks for the assistance: the file is being written to, but it is inserting the row twice.  I just want it to insert the row if the ip address is once in the file already, and to skip it if it already resides twice in the file

Comment: My code is for writing into a new file, so data will be entered fresh. So, it will write data corresponding to a single IP address twice at max.

Comment: Are you trying to write into the source file (the one you read from) while using the approach I mentioned? You should write into a new file.